# Редирект из вью в ангуляр (jwt токен)

Tags: vue.js, angular, jwt

Имеется два сайта.

**(1)** -> публичная часть написанная на вью. Имеется форма. (3000 хост)

**(2)** -> админка, написанная на ангуляре. Имеется форма. (4200 хост)

На сайте 1 вводим логин и пароль (при нужной роли получаем 301), получаем jwt токен. Также нас перебрасывает на сайт 2.

```
if(response.status == 301) {
 request.post('/admin/api/sessions/sign_in', {
  email: this.login,
  password: this.password,
  token: response.data.token
 }).then(() => {
  window.location = 'http://localhost:4200/auth/sign-in';
 });
}
```

Нужно на сайте 2 заходит автоматически, по jwt токену.

Куда нужно записать токен и как его использовать на сайте 2, дабы совершить автоматический вход?

**auth.service**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  
  
  public checkSession(): Observable<IEmployee> {
    return this.http.get<IEmployee>(`${environment.apiUrl}/admin/api/sessions`);
  }

  public login(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<IEmployee>(`${environment.apiUrl}/admin/api/sessions/sign_in`, { email, password });
  }
}
```

**sign-in.page.ts**

```
    @Component({
  templateUrl: './sign-in.page.html'
})
export class SignInPage implements OnInit {
  public form: FormGroup;
  public loading = false;
  public invalidForm = false;

  constructor(private builder: FormBuilder, private store: Store, private actions: Actions, private http: HttpClient) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.builder.group({
      email: [null, Validators.required],
      password: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    });
    
    this.actions.pipe(ofActionDispatched(LoginSuccess)).subscribe(() => (this.loading = false));
    this.actions.pipe(ofActionDispatched(LoginFailed)).subscribe(() => {
      this.invalidForm = true;
      this.loading = false;
    });
  }

  public onSubmit() {
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    this.loading = true;
    this.invalidForm = false;
    const { email, password } = this.form.value;
    this.store.dispatch(new Login(email, password ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, передавать токен в параметрах url, только не в лоб, а предварительно зашифровав, используя фингерпринт браузера и секрет в качестве ключа. Это нужно, чтобы токен не увели через сниффинг трафика. Не знаю насколько этот способ будет безопасен, может светлые умы в комментариях напишут. Тут несколько вариантов: это либо конкретный такой оверкилл и можно обойтись без фингерпринта, либо есть вариант попроще и побезопаснее, либо этот способ вообще не сработает так, как это должно сработать в теории.

**ЭТО ТОЛЬКО ТЕОРИЯ!** Используется ли такой подход на практике где-то, я не знаю, сам с такими проблемами не сталкивался. Если найдется что-то попроще, то мне самому будет интересно на это посмотреть.

Насчет удобства такого подхода я особо не думал, я знаю, что его можно улучшить/успростить и т.д. Ниже будет просто попытка передать саму суть идеи.

Итак, как это должно отработать с обоих сторон:

## Vue

---

#### Получаем фингерпринт браузера клиента

Фингерпринт - это "слепок" браузера. Т.е данные, которые можно выудить о машине пользователя от банального `navigator.userAgent` до вендора GPU.
Для получения слепка можно воспользоваться библиотектой [fingerprintjs](https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs).

*Код из [документации](https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs/blob/master/docs/api.md) fingerprintjs*

```
import FingerprintJS from '@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs'

// Initialize an agent at application startup.
const fpPromise = FingerprintJS.load()

;(async () => {
  // Get the visitor identifier when you need it.
  const fp = await fpPromise
  const result = await fp.get()
  console.log(result.visitorId)
})();
```

#### Шифруем объект токен-фингерпринт

Тут есть над чем подумать. Для начала, определиться с алгоритмом шифрования. Допустим, что это `HS256`. Восопльзуемся библиотектой [CryptoJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js)

```
const hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(
  response.data.token, fingerprint + '<СЕКРЕТНЫЙ КЛЮЧ>'
);
```

Таким образом мы получим хэш примерно такого вида:

```
isevUNuRP6HflG8cJKnmUPtypruRC4fb1DWtoLL62SY=
```

Расшифровать его можно только связкой хэша слепка браузера и секрета, т.к этот общий хзш является ключом. Секретный ключ можно/нужно менять с необходимой вам периодичностью. Этот ключ должен быть неизвестен никому, и запрашиваться с сервера, где он будет переодически генерироваться.
Этот хэш мы и отправим в url параметре на другой ресурс на Angular.

```
const url = new URL('http://localhost:4200/auth/sign-in');
      url.searchParams.append('user', hash);
window.open(url.toString());
```

Даже если этот хэш попадет в плохие руки, то расшифровать его будет непросто, по крайней мере не быстро. Скорее всего, его не успеют расшифровать до того, как сменится секретный ключ.

## Angular

---

Теперь, чтобы получить наш JWT обратно, нужно сделать все в обратном порядке.

#### Читаем параметры запроса

Прочитать параметры из текущего `location` можно с помощью `ActivatedRoute`.

**sign-in.page.ts**

```
constructor(private builder: FormBuilder, private store: Store, private actions: Actions, private http: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    //...
    this.route.queryParams
        .pipe(filter((params) => params.user))
        .pipe(map((params) => params.user))
        .pipe(switchMap((hash) => combineLatest([of(hash), from(FingerprintJS.load())])))
        .pipe(switchMap(([hash, fingerprint]) => of(CryptoJS.HmacSHA256.decrypt(hash, fingerprint.get()).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)))
        .subscribe((token) => {
          console.log(token); // И делаете с ним что хотите. Скорее всего вы захотите отправить его на сервер для валидации
        });
    //...
  }
//...
}
```

Дальше дело за малым, отправляем запрос с токеном в заголовке запроса на сервер для валидации, если он валиден, логинимся, иначе остаемся на странице логина.

Код, который я предоставил выше не тестировался, и если захотите все это провернуть, то не копируйте бездумно, смотрите в документацию! Технологии я тоже не навязываю, используйте что хотите, на свое усмотрение. Этот ответ только описывает саму концепцию, а код просто для наглядности.